# Nginx - multilple proxy endpoints under same server name

Tags: linux, nginx, server, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I have a react application along with backend application inside the same project. The structure is as follows.

myapp -> src -> api

To run this app in my localhost i have to start both my backend and frontend apps. So for that what i do is

1. inside `myapp` run `npm start` - front end app opens in localhost:3000
2. inside `api` run `npm start`

Then the full app works without an issue.

I want to host this app. So i have started both FE and BE apps inside my server using npm start. And i have pointed `http:localhost:3000` to my server. But my BE is in `http:localhost:9000`. How can i configure nginx to serve both at the same time.

My current nginx server block is as follows.

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   server_name myservername.com www.myservername.com;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }

}
```

Comment: You can use different proxy locations. Would you like to host you backend under a subdomain or different location. Like `something.myservername.com` or `myservername.com/services`?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to configure 2 locations which do not collide

```
 location /api/ {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
     }
   location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
   }
```

The`/api/*` requests go to the backend, all others to the frontend